# Using Stripe and Mailgun in Custom Webhook hosted on WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments, webhooks

Hello Stackoverflowers!

I have been in a really big bind trying to solve this configuration/implementation of a webhook that utilizes both the Stripe PHP library and the Mailgun API. My intention is to send an email (with Mailgun) whenever one of my Stripe customers performs a certain action which has been recorded as an event in my Stripe endpoint. I have been trying to follow the guidelines of this documentation https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments but unfortunately I think I am missing something in my understanding of how to make this work. I have a SiteGround hosted WordPress site which I am trying to host my webhook.php file and Stripe PHP library on. I uploaded the entire Stripe PHP library (in a folder named "stripe-php-master") to my "/wp-includes/" directory. In the webhook.php file I changed the boilerplate code in the documentation (https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/sending-emails-for-failed-payments) from

```
// If you're using Composer, use Composer's autoload
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

to

```
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/init.php';
require_once($file);
```

because I am not sure how to utilize "Composer" in this scenario within the confines/context of of a SiteGround hosted WordPress site, so I figured this may be a suitable approach (according to https://packagist.org/packages/stripe/stripe-php) please correct me if I am wrong! When I try to visit the URL of my webhook.php file at https://mysitename.com/wp-includes/stripe-php-master/webhook.php I receive this error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mailgun\Mailgun' not found in /home/mysitef3/public_html/wp-includes/stripe-php-master/webhook.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/mysitef3/public_html/wp-includes/stripe-php-master/webhook.php on line 16". Could any of you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here please and thank you!!!

Comment: That error says you don't have the Mailgun library actually included in your application, so make sure you're also `require_once`ing the Mailgun library.

Comment: Do I need to physically host the entire Mailgun Library in my "/wp-includes/" folder similar to how I am hosting the Stripe PHP Library?

Comment: You need to have it somewhere - and reference it in your script - yes.

Comment: and as long as I have the "require_once" statement pointing to the correct location of the Mailgun library on my server I never need to reference the full path when using Mailgun utilities in my code? Is there a Mailgun init.php file or something of the sort similar to how the Stripe library has me using the init.php file in my require statement?

Comment: You need to install Mailgun however Mailgun needs you to install it: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php#installation
It looks like it requires Composer.